# Why must the first 3 characters of an Intel 4004 label be unique?

Tags: assembly, microprocessors

From the user manual for Intel's 4004 Microprocessor

[image]

It says that the first 3 characters of a label should be unique, as the assembler may not be able to differentiate it from other labels. Why is this is the case, and what workarounds are there?

Comment: here's an online assembler that has 6 significant characters! http://e4004.szyc.org/asm.html

Comment: historical "why" questions tend to get better answers on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/.  The obvious answer is that the assembler only actually stores the first 3 bytes of label names so its internal data structures can be fixed-width.

Answer (score 3):

Compilers and assemblers back in the day ran on very limited hardware.  The first C compiler I used only used the first 6 characters of variable names.  The Intel assembler is no different.  Limited resources means making trades-offs.

we are talking about the 1970s.  Memory was very limited, CPUs were many, many orders of magnitude slower. You would need a very efficient way to store and lookup the labels.

I doubt there is any workaround for the original assembler. I'd be impressed if you could even run the assembler that the book is referring to. Try writing a new one.  Assemblers are easy to write, especially with the computers and tools available today. My 2nd year CS programming assignment was to write an assembler...